Why is it still considered acceptable to publish papers without also sharing the original data and code?
Given the "replication crisis" and numerous examples of outright fraud in academia in the past decades, why do reputable journals still accept papers where the authors don't share 100% of their data and code along with the paper? This would make replication attempts a lot easier and somewhat deter fraudulent researchers.
Also see: Are there any proposals to make sharing code and data with publications a requirement?

Related / possible duplicate: Why are papers without code but with results accepted? (also this one)

@cag51 it's been a decade since, I think we need a fresh question

@JonathanReez Looking it over, the reasons haven't changed, so why do we need a fresh question?

If you are doing research on people, there are competing interests with replicability and privacy of the respondents. So there are legitimate cases where the data cannot be made public. The data can still be made available to people wanting to replicate it, but depending on how sensitive the data is that access could be more or less convenient.

^ medical data being one example

@MaartenBuis maybe you shouldn't be allowed to publish papers if you're not allowed to share the dataset used for the analysis? Or at least such papers should receive intense scrutiny and be presumed fraudulent by default.

As JackRed mentioned, this is an important issue in medical research. I hope you are not suggesting that we stop doing medical research... The main point is that there is no one solution that works in all situations.

@MaartenBuis I highly doubt there's a dataset that you couldn't just publish after removing personal info like exact names and birthdates

@JonathanReez You are free to doubt, but it would be even better if you did your research. An easy, and possibly pleasant, way to do that is to just invite a member of the IRB in your institution to a coffee and discuss that with her/him/them.
